# Avoiding compiling certain lines based on template operator existence

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, sfinae

I'm currently creating a template container class in which I like to have a sorting ability whenever the template class has the comparison operator.

With SFINAE I can determine if the operator exist during runtime. However, when compiling the code below it of course still tries to compile the line containing `sort`, which will return compiler errors if the compare operator is not specified for that class.

Is there a way to 'avoid' compiling that line if the comparison operator doesn't exist? Not knowing the naming of such procedure, something like an '#ifdef SFINAE'?

```
template <class UseClass> class Container {
public:
    bool Sort(void) {
        if (CHECK::opCompareExists<UseClass>::value) {
            sort(m_classlist.begin(),m_classlist.end());    //compile error, of course
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
private:
    vector<UseClass> m_classlist;
};
```

Maybe I shouldn't use SFINAE at all... maybe it should be a template specification? How would that work (based on automatic detection that the operator is not present)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::sort()` by default uses the less-than operator (`operator<()`) to compare elements so you can simply use expression SFINAE to rule out a specific overload if the type doesn't have it:

```c++
template<typename T = UseClass>
auto Sort() -> decltype(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>(), bool())
{
    return true;
}
```

If substitution fails (`SomeClass` does not have `operator<()`) then compilation will fail.

If this wasn't your intention, and instead you wanted to return true if it could sort and false otherwise, then you need a trait class that you can overload based on:

```c++
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T>
    auto has_less_than_impl(int)
        -> decltype(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>(), std::true_type());

    template<typename>
    std::false_type has_less_than_impl(...);
}

template<typename T>
struct has_less_than : decltype(detail::has_less_than_impl<T>(0)) { };

template <class UseClass> class Container
{
public:
    bool Sort() { return Sort(has_less_than<UseClass>::value); }
private:
    bool Sort(std::true_type)
    {
        sort(m_classlist.begin(), m_classlist.end());
        return true;
    }

    bool Sort(std::false_type) { return false; }
};
```

**Update:** As per your comment here is a C++03 implementation:

```c++
template <typename T>
class has_less_than {
    struct Fallback { bool operator<(T const&); };
    struct Derived : T, Fallback {};

    template <typename U, U> struct S;

    template <typename C> static char (&f(S<bool (Fallback::*)(T const&), &C::operator<>*))[1];
    template <typename C> static char (&f(...))[2];

public:
    const static bool value = sizeof(f<Derived>(0)) == 2;
};

namespace detail
{
    template <bool B, typename R = void>
    struct enable_if { typedef R type; };

    template <typename R>
    struct enable_if<false, R> { };
}

template <class UseClass> class Container {
public:
    bool Sort() { return Sort<UseClass>(); }
private:
    template <typename T>
    bool Sort(typename detail::enable_if<has_less_than<T>::value, int>::type = 0) {
        sort(m_classlist.begin(),m_classlist.end());
        return true;
    }

    template <typename T>
    bool Sort(typename detail::enable_if<!has_less_than<T>::value, int>::type = 0) {
        return false;
    }
private:
    vector<UseClass> m_classlist;
};
```

Comment: My intention is to have the function no matter what, but implement `std::sort` and return true whenever the UseClass has the operator, but not implement `std::sort` and return false whenever the UseClass doesn't have the operator. Also, I notice you use C++11, while I'm using C++03. My apologies if I should have specified that (at least my question's tag doesn't mention C++11).

Comment: @DoubleYou I'll add an implementation for C++03.